# make a button to change the parent's CSS classname attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

so I have a javascript function that changes the class name of a div

```
function flip (event)
{
  var element = event.currentTarget;
  element.className = (element.className == 'card') ? 'card flipped' : 'card';
}
```

How can I make it so my `onclick="flip(event)"` can be attached to a button (or preferably an image) and the button will then flip the card instead of just clicking inside the div. So something like

```
<div id="card" class="card">
  <p>
    whatever
  </p>
<img onclick="flip(event)" src="foo">
</div>
```

What do I need to change in my javascript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think that John solution's can have problem if you have several elements with class 'card' and you only want to change the one that was clicked.

To do this, use 'this' as argument :

```
<img onclick="javascript:flip(this.parentElement);" />

function flip (element) 
{ 
  element.className = (element.className == 'card') ? 'card flipped' : 'card'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<img onclick="javascript:flip('card');" />

function flip (elementId) 
{ 
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId)
  element.className = (element.className == 'card') ? 'card flipped' : 'card'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('imgSelector').click(function() {`

$(".card").toggleClass('card flipped');

});

Using jQuery you can do it Like this.

with Simple javascript you will have to give a id to your DIV. and then instead of using event.target just simply use document.getElementById('myDIVID');

Comment: the question does not specify jquery.

Answer (score 0):

the `event` object has a reference to the element that originated the event.
you can use `parentNode` to work back up the tree.

this will work with your html example.

```
function flip (event)
{
    var image = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var div = image.parentNode;
    div.className = (div.className == 'card') ? 'card flipped' : 'card';
}
```

`target` is the originating element in ff/chrome, `srcElement` is the same element in IE. `currentTarget` in ff/chrome is the element which called the handler, which may not be the same element you clicked on. for example, if you attached a click handler right on the div, it would fire when you clicked on the image within. when the div's handler fires, `currentTarget` would be the div and `target` would be the image. IE has no parallel for `currentTarget` that i'm aware of.

Comment: well... IE's Lack of parallel's never seems to end!  This was very informative.  I'm sure by the nature of my question it's apparent that I have alot to learn about javascript.  This helps me understand how my fix worked.  Cheers!